# React - Enable/Disable field in Component Slot

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an odd scenario. I have a component that includes a slot. That slot will have content that must include an input field for a name. By default, that field will be disabled until a web request has been made within the component. When the web request has completed, I need to set the input field to be either enabled or disabled based on what the web request returns.

This feels like I'm doing it incorrectly. It feels like an anti-pattern. Yet, these are my constraints.

How do I set the input field, passed in via a slot, to be enabled / disabled, based on the response from the web request?

Comment: Control the enabled/disabled flag in state, initialize that state value to be disabled, conditionally update that state value in the response of the AJAX request.  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of example, I'm assuming your code looks something like this.

```
function Parent() {
  return <Component slot={<Input/>}/>;
}

function Component({slot}) {
  const request = useRequest();
  // This is obviously invalid!
  return <div>{slot disabled={!request.isFinished()}</div>;
}
```

Do you have *any* flexibility to change this interface? If you need the ability for the component's caller to specify the input field, you can keep that with a [render prop](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement#passing-data-with-a-render-prop). For example:

```
function MyComponent({renderSlot}) {
  function Parent() {
  return <Component renderSlot={({disabled}) => <Input disabled={disabled} />}/>;
}

function Component({renderSlot}) {
  const request = useRequest();
  const Slot = renderSlot;
  return <div><Slot disabled={!request.isFinished()} /></div>;
}
```

If you really need to keep the current interface, you can probably use React's [cloneElement](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement).

```
function Parent() {
  return <Component slot={<Input/>}/>;
}

function Component({slot}) {
  const request = useRequest();
  const customSlot = cloneElement(slot, { disabled: !request.isFinished() });
  return <div>{customSlot}</div>;
}
```

The React docs [cloneElement page](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement#) has additional information and other alternatives.